# Allow multiple roles to access controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, roles

Right now I decorate a method like this to allow "members" to access my controller action

```
[Authorize(Roles="members")]
```

**How do I allow more than one role?** For example the following does not work but it shows what I am trying to do (allow "members" and "admin" access):

```
[Authorize(Roles="members", "admin")]
```

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to this question.  The person with the currently accepted answer edited it indicating that he was wrong.

Answer (score 680):

Another option is to use a single authorize filter as you posted but remove the inner quotations.

```
[Authorize(Roles="members,admin")]
```

Comment: Works in MVC 5 too. +1

Comment: Works in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (MVC 6) and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity v3.*

Comment: This is okay if you only have one controller that you need to authorize. If you have more than one, you're duplicating those string constants (yuck). I much prefer the static class that has the role names. My pet hate is duplicate strings... so so bad.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot get this to work.  It's fine if I specify [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")], but not if I specify [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, PowerUser")].  I'm using MVC v5.2.7

Comment: So now I'm testing a custom attribute inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute.  It's okay with just Administrator, it hits my break point in HandleUnauthorizedRequest just fine, but if I specify Administrator and PowerUser, it doesn't hit the break point at all and access is granted to the action.  What the?!?

Comment: Never mind.  I think it's a cookies issue.  My user still appears to be logged in.

Comment: @kraeg good news that you solved your problem. Now, consider deleting your comments, please

Comment: Why?  It took me ages to work this out.  It may be helpful for someone else experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Why? Because it is very long, SO cuts it, and nobody reads completely when seeing the answer. At best it could condense everything into a single brief comment.

Comment: Only to add some more info on this issue... This answer is not completely correct. If you go to the Roles Authorization assign, it does this split: original.Split(','))
So if you have any spaces on the Roles name, it won't work!! Be careful with that. Just use the same solution as @Jim Schmehil suggests, but with no spaces on your role names

Comment: extra note: as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#adding-role-checks - this is `OR` and not `AND`

Answer (score 162):

If you want use custom roles, you can do this:

`CustomRoles` class:

```
public static class CustomRoles
{
    public const string Administrator = "Administrador";
    public const string User = "Usuario";
}
```

Usage

```
[Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.Administrator +","+ CustomRoles.User)]
```

If you have few roles, maybe you can combine them (for clarity) like this:

```
public static class CustomRoles
{
     public const string Administrator = "Administrador";
     public const string User = "Usuario";
     public const string AdministratorOrUser = Administrator + "," + User;  
}
```

Usage

```
[Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.AdministratorOrUser)]
```

Comment: This would be a good answer, if you explained to people who didn't know what's behind CustomRoles.

Comment: @JamesSkemp ok, i've extended my answer. It is very simple. CustumRoles is a class that i created that contains some constants, that corresponds with my application roles. I did that for a few reasons: 1) It allow the use of intellisense to avoid spelling mistakes 2)To simplify maintenance. If a role change, i have to update only one place within my application.

Comment: @Pabloker Alternatively you can create an enum with an Flags attribute, e.g. Convert.ToString(CustomRoles.Administrator | CustomRoles.User); - annoying part is that this requires an explicit conversion

Comment: If you have 39 roles ?

Comment: I think your problem goes through the modeling of permits beyond what can be done with .net

Answer (score 107):

One possible simplification would be to subclass `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
public class RolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public RolesAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        Roles = String.Join(",", roles);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[Roles("members", "admin")]
```

Semantically it is the same as Jim Schmehil's answer.

Comment: This does not worked for me, the logged in user was able to bypass the attribute even if the user did not have any of the roles.

Comment: This answer is better for when you are using constants as your values: ie [Roles(Constants.Admin,Constants.Owner)]

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: I know this is an old post, but let me add this. In order for this code snippet to work, you have to use `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` for `System.Web.Mvc.Controllers` and `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` for `System.Web.Http.ApiController` (RESTful calls).

Answer (score 19):

For MVC4, using a `Enum` (`UserRoles`) with my roles, I use a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`.

On my controlled action, I do:

```
[CustomAuthorize(UserRoles.Admin, UserRoles.User)]
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    return View();
}
```

And I use a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` like that:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string[] UserProfilesRequired { get; set; }

    public CustomAuthorize(params object[] userProfilesRequired)
    {
        if (userProfilesRequired.Any(p => p.GetType().BaseType != typeof(Enum)))
            throw new ArgumentException("userProfilesRequired");

        this.UserProfilesRequired = userProfilesRequired.Select(p => Enum.GetName(p.GetType(), p)).ToArray();
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        bool authorized = false;

        foreach (var role in this.UserProfilesRequired)
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role))
            {
                authorized = true;
                break;
            }

        if (!authorized)
        {
            var url = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
            var logonUrl = url.Action("Http", "Error", new { Id = 401, Area = "" });
            context.Result = new RedirectResult(logonUrl);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of modifed FNHMVC by Fabricio Martínez Tamayo https://github.com/fabriciomrtnz/FNHMVC/

Comment: Your OnAuthorization method will require the user to have **all** the enumerated roles; was that intentional, or are you missing a break in that loop?

Comment: @Tieson: I inspected that pretty closely, it definitely seems like a break would be required in that loop.

Comment: @TiesonT.  and @ madrush, I appreciate your fix, it really could have a break inside the loop. I'll change the code above.

Comment: The enum *UserRoles* is nice. Do you declare it manually or is it autogenerated based on the contents of the DB?

Comment: @KonradViltersten It's manually but I guess with Reflection and Dynamic class autogenerated can be done

Comment: Overriding OnAuthorization is a bad idea. There is some code which protects against cached pages being served up in the original. Check the source.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Authorization Policy
in Startup.cs

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("SuperAdmin","Admin"));
        options.AddPolicy("teacher", policy => policy.RequireRole("SuperAdmin", "Admin", "Teacher"));
    });
```

And in Controller Files:

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "teacher")]
 [HttpGet("stats/{id}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> getStudentStats(int id)
 { ... }
```

"teacher" policy accept 3 roles.

Comment: Is it AND or OR?

Comment: This was my preference. Also, in the new versions that do not have startup.cs you do the same thing now in program.cs.  If you need different combinations you'll have to create a policy for each one, but then you don't have to put the Domain groups in the controller. you can put them in the AppSettings.json file.

Answer (score 4):

Another clear solution, you can use constants to keep convention and add multiple [Authorize] attributes. Check this out:

```
public static class RolesConvention
{
    public const string Administrator = "Administrator";
    public const string Guest = "Guest";
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = RolesConvention.Administrator )]
[Authorize(Roles = RolesConvention.Guest)]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
```

Comment: Multiple `Authorize` attributes employ AND semantics and require ALL conditions to be met (i.e. user has to be in both the Administrator and Guest roles).

Answer (score 4):

Using AspNetCore 2.x, you have to go a little different way:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRoleAttribute(params YourEnum[] roles)
    {
        Policy = string.Join(",", roles.Select(r => r.GetDescription()));
    }
}
```

just use it like this:

```
[Authorize(YourEnum.Role1, YourEnum.Role2)]
```

Comment: `Policy = ` or `Roles = `?

Comment: Roles = string.Join(",", roles.Select(r => r.ToString()));

Answer (score 4):

I mixed answers and proposed this method.

Firstly, We create an enum for role accesses.

```
public enum ERoleAccess
{
     [Description("Admin User")]
     Admin = 1,

     [Description("General User")]
     User = 2,

     [Description("Editor User")]
     Editor = 3,
}
```

Secondly, we need an attribute filter for customer MVC authorize.

```
public class RolesAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute
{
   public RolesAttribute(params ERoleAccess[] roles)
   {
      Roles = string.Join(",", roles);
   }
}
```

Finally, we can use "RolesAttribute" on the controllers or actions.

```
[Roles(ERoleAccess.Admin, ERoleAccess.Editor, ERoleAccess.User)]
```

In this approach, we use numbers of alternative string values.
(1= Admin, 2=User,...)

It's good for decreasing token size and comparing performance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Better code with adding a subclass `AuthorizeRole.cs`

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    class AuthorizeRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public AuthorizeRoleAttribute(params Rolenames[] roles)
        {
            this.Roles = string.Join(",", roles.Select(r => Enum.GetName(r.GetType(), r)));
        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                  { "action", "Unauthorized" },
                  { "controller", "Home" },
                  { "area", "" }
                  }
              );
                //base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                  { "action", "Login" },
                  { "controller", "Account" },
                  { "area", "" },
                  { "returnUrl", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url }
                  }
              );
            }
        }
    }
```

How to use this

```
[AuthorizeRole(Rolenames.Admin,Rolenames.Member)]

public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself applying those 2 roles often you can wrap them in their own Authorize. This is really an extension of the accepted answer.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class AuthorizeAdminOrMember : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeAdminOrMember()
    {
        Roles = "members, admin";
    }
}
```

And then apply your new authorize to the Action. I think this looks cleaner and reads easily.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [AuthorizeAdminOrMember]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For "Or" you need comma between roles

```
[Authorize(Roles="members,admin")]
```

both members and admins can access

But for "and" you need

```
[Authorize(Roles="manager")]
[Authorize(Roles="sales")]
```

managers who are in sales can access.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
[Authorize(Roles="members")]
```

will work when the `AND` is needed (as asked by question) whereas [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503873/2361131) answer shows the `OR` version.
See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#adding-role-checks

Answer (score -11):

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8081/MyAPPStore/apk/Teflouki.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );

startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Comment: Answers including code should have at least a minumum description explaining how the code works and why it answers to the question. Furthermode the code section formatting needs to be improved.