# Multiple roles in Controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i try to create custom role provider in mvc4 to give user access in my site.
when i try to using role provider is success.

i success create role provider like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

my question is, can i use more then one role name in controller?
i mean like.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

try to use this code, but not working for me. any one can show me how does it work?
thanks

Comment: yeah.... work now... thanks @Zabavsky

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action) question has the answer for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin,userRole")]
```