# ASP.NET CORE MVC / How can i assign 2 Identity roles on same Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

Basically i want to do this [IMGUR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRAxe.png)

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin" )]  <= Currently it's like this.
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin","SuperAdmin" )] <= I want to make it like this.

Basically i want to assign 2 identity roles at once to the same Controller,but I'm not sure how to format it properly. I made 2 identity roles, Admin and SuperAdmin, so i want SuperAdmin to be able to access everything that Admin can, so that's why i need to assign 2 identity roles on the same stuff.

Comment: please explain your question instead of sending the readers to links to figure out the problem

Comment: I literally couldn't be more specific. I perfectly explained what i want to achieve and i gave an image example. I don't understand what more information can i possibly provide....

Comment: If you wanted to include a snapshot etc, it is always recommended to use the embedded images since links break and the posts become useless or incomplete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow multiple roles to access controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]