# In C#, how can I allow users to different methods based on their individual roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

There are currently 3 roles - `Admin`, `Manager` and `Writer`. 
There are some methods inside `HomeController` and most of them are common for both `Admin` and `Manager`, few for only `Admin`, and few for `Writer`. There are around 30 methods. And 25 will be common for Admin and Manager, 1-2 for only Admnin. And 1-2 for all of 3 roles.

- Only 1 method named `ForWriterOnly()` should be available for everyone
- Writer should not have access to any of other methods, but Admin and Manager should have access
- There are some methods which are only for Admin, and not for Manager and Writer

What is the best way to achieve the 3 cases mentioned above ? How can I exclude Writer for most of the other methods except `ForWriterOnly()` ? And how can I exclude `Admin` for accessing some other methods ?

I know I could write `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]` for those 25 common methods for Admin and Manager but I am looking for a simpler solution.

**Please make modifications in my code so that it will be easier to understand.**

---

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager, Writer")]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {

        public async Task<IActionResult> ForEveryone()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> ForWriterOnly()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminOnly()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager1()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager2()
        {
            return View();
        }
        ...........
        // There are around 30 other methods which are common for both Admin and Manager

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager, Writer")]` above your controller then this will provide access to your entire **HomeController** and its actions to **Admin, Manager, Writer** Roles.

There are several ways of achieving this, but in my opinion I'd seperate my controllers. But for simplicity I will continue on your situation.

```
 // Normally your controller will be accessible by only Authenticated users.
 [Authorize]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {

        //In here you want your action to be accessible by everyone.
        //So you dont have to give any attributes in here.
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForEveryone()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "Writer")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForWriterOnly()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize (Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminOnly()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager1()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager2()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Specified Roles For each Action.

[Allow multiple roles to access controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action)

If use **[Authorize]** above Controller. you should use **[AllowAnonymous]** for actions that you want accessible by **everyone**.

[Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
 [Authorize]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForEveryone()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Writer")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForWriterOnly()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize (Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminOnly()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForAdminAndManager2()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

}