# Simple authorization question to allow more than one user type

Tags: c#, api, authorization

I have 3 roles in my api:

1. user
2. admin
3. guest

While testing out my front-end I've mostly used the admin role, but now there are some methods I want to use two roles for.

```
//GET: api/Job
[Authorize(Roles = Role.Admin)]
[Authorize(Roles = Role.User)]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Job>>> GetJob()
{
    ... code
}
```

Writing it this way does not produce the wanted result: the method should be accessible by both admins and users, instead you need to be both an admin and a user, so my front-end automatically logs you out no matter who you log in as. How can I rewrite the Authorize to allow both roles?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow multiple roles to access controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a comma delimited list of roles that are allowed to access the resource.
/// </summary>
public string Roles { get; set; }
```

That's mean instead of multiple AuthorizeAttribute you need to use comma separated list of roles.

```
[Authorize(Roles = Role.Admin + "," + Role.User)]
```