# How to add "Role Or Policy" to Authorize in .net Core

Tags: api, asp.net-core

Can i make Authorize Like this in .net Core API:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SUPPORT") OR Policy = "SuperUser"]
public IActionResult MyMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

mean if user has "SUPPORT" role OR has "SuperUser" Police can access to MyMethod.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow multiple roles to access controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action)

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, I suggest you could put multiple Authorize attribute to achieve your requirement.

Like below:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SuperUser")]
[Authorize(Roles = "SUPPORT")]
public IActionResult MyMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Stacking attributes will result in an AND condition where the policy must be true and the user must have the roles as well.